# ActionbarSherlock list navigation - scroll to top/focus first row

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I need some help with sherlock list navigation.
Goal: when you open navigation, I want scroll to top/focus to first row, so 1st item is always visible.
Problem: now when list has more items as screen can display(usually in landscape mode), when i select ie 4th item and then open list, first item is not visible, it's focused to last selected item.
It works for me with code bellow in custom spinner, but when I tried override same methods in IcsSpinner it haven't worked.

Code:

```
/**
```

* Cusrom spinner class - when open always focus on first item
 * 
 */
class CustomSpinnerSelection extends Spinner {

```
private boolean mToggleFlag = true;

//some constructors here

@Override
public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
    // this toggle is required because this method will get called in other
    // places too, the most important being called for the
    // OnItemSelectedListener
    if (!mToggleFlag) {
        return 0; // get us to the first element
    }
    return super.getSelectedItemPosition();
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    // this method shows the list of elements from which to select one.
    // we have to make the getSelectedItemPosition to return 0 so you can
    // fool the Spinner and let it think that the selected item is the first
    // element
    mToggleFlag = false;
    boolean result = super.performClick();
    mToggleFlag = true;
    return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There is one possible way of doing so, now that you've done it with spinner.

You can use custom view for the action bar, that contains a spinner for list navigation, and use your custom spinner class instead of the default spinner.

The custom view xml might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/actionBarSpinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/default_list" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You will need to enable and set custom view from code.

```
View view = this.getLayoutInflater ().inflate (R.layout.actionbar_customview, null);
actionBar.setCustomView (view);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled (true);
```

Also, you can save the spinner to set any listeners or do any other operations.

```
Spinner actionBarSpinner = ((Spinner) view.findViewById (R.id.actionBarSpinner));
```

Just instead of Spinner, it would be your CustomSpinner class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your case, but one thing I found out about spinners: sometimes if you populate them on onCreate(), a little bit of low-level trickiness happens. Remember that Android is event-based, so putting the data in onCreate actually might not fill the spinner. The spinner sometimes gets filled after the screen is drawn!

So, if this is happening, try doing in a call after onCreate like onWindowFocused or whatever it's called

Comment: I fill spinner after screen is drawn, because I load spinner items from DB through Cursorloader. What I want is to scroll to top when I open navigation menu. It works this way in gmail app(if you try it in landscape mode)

Answer (score 0):

setSelection might be the only way to load the spinner with the first item focused. Try this:

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);
int i = adapter.getPosition("blue");
s.setSelection(i);
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved it with spinner, I need it with ActionbarSherlock list navigation